# Cross platform mobile file upload - possible?

Tags: iphone, android, file, upload, cross-platform

I need as simple as possible solution for uploading files (eg. photos) to my website from mobile devices (iPhone, Android, BB, Nokia). Is it possible to do it in same way? Using Java or XHTML?

Answer (score 0):

To upload files to your server and render it the most interoperable as possible, I should you to use a REST API for the server side. After you'll have to call the proper service using the PUT method.

If you want design your server with Java you can use Tomcat and the servlet.
you can find a tutorial here: [How do I upload a file to a servlet?](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-upload-a-file-to-a-servlet.html)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cliqcliq.com/support/quickpic/ is an iPhone app that will allow you to upload photos to a website.

I've used it before and it's great.  Now, i'm trying to find something similar to use for android phones.

Comment: Find anything similar for droid?